# Spring boot Junit with spring security Authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

Below is my code for junit test

```
  MvcResult mvcResult = (MvcResult) mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put(uri).headers(headers)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json)).andReturn();
```

and I need to include authentication in the above code. username is 'admin' and password is also 'admin'.

How to do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have already the headers in the `headers` variable. Here you can set your authorization header:
`headers.setBasicAuth("admin", "admin");`